# How to apply distinct based on field instead of has code of the object (rxjava2)

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I've got the following code:
Observable1, Observable2 (Object contains UUID field).

```
Observable1.mergeWith(Observable2).distinct().map(...)
```

And then I'd like to apply distinct() based on .UUID field instead of .hashcode. As it is, distinct() doesn't work (in fact, I can remove it and I'll get the same result) cause these observables emit different objects.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used .distinct(object -> object.UUID)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs you can use a KeySelector as a parameter. From [source](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#distinct-rx.functions.Func1-)

> ```
> public final <U> Observable<T> distinct(Func1<? super T,? extends U> keySelector)
> ```
>
> Returns an Observable that emits all items emitted by the source
>   Observable that are distinct according to a key selector function.

Should be able to pass in the getter method as the parameter:

```
Observable1.mergeWith(Observable2).distinct(MyObject::getUUID).map(...)
```